# Does the cloudkit dashboard deployment include subscription and recordZones for private data?

Tags: cloudkit

I'm using cloudkit private data and did define a recordZone and a subscription. Everything works as expected. The only problem is, that I can not see the subscription for the recordZone in the dashboard ( I do can see subscriptions for the public database).

My questions are now, am I doing something wrong or

1. is it true that the dashboard does not show the subscriptions on private data?
2. The apple docs say

> The first time you deploy your app, CloudKit copies the container
>   schema to the production environment. This includes the record types,
>   security roles, and subscription types, but not the records that you
>   created in the development environment.

what is going to happen with the defined recordZone - do I have to set it up in production or is it going to be deployed as well? ( If not - how could it deploy then a subscription on a zone which is not there?)

Many thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Made a test, the recordZone and the subscriptions are NOT deployed to production. However still wondering why I can not see the subscription in the dashboard as long as the subscription is against the recordZone.

Comment: does the subscription still work and is just hidden from the dashboard?

Comment: exactly - it is not visible but it works!

Comment: Slightly off-topic question just in case :) Me and some test users are using the dev CloudKit, when we publish the app and download it from App Store, will the data be lost in production version? Anyway to share in both environment? Thanks!

Comment: The data will be lost, i.e. you will get only the structure. I'm not aware of a possibility to share data (prod/dev. I would guess that it is intentionaly not possible.